# Overflow x disappears but shouldn't

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a site, were different pictures are placed next to each other, so I have a large line of pictures. These pictures aren't visible after a specific width.

When I created the site, I could use `overflow-x:visible;` to show the scrollbar. This was the solution I needed and I wanted.
I just updated the content of the site and saw, that the scrollbar disappears after the page loaded.

The problem is, that no one can access the pictures at the right without the scrollbar. How can I force the browsers to always show the scrollbar? `overflow-x:scroll;` didn't work.

HTML

```
<section class="scroll">
                <ul class="detail-images-list">
                    <li>
                        <article class="image-detail">
                            <img src="../bilder/gallery-10/1.jpg">
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="image-detail">
                            <img src="../bilder/gallery-10/2.jpg">
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="image-detail">
                            <img src="../bilder/gallery-10/3.jpg">
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="image-detail">
                            <img src="../bilder/gallery-10/4.jpg">
                        </article>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

CSS

```
.scroll {
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
height:51.5em;
min-width:100%;
```

}

Comment: You'll need to show some code. Are you sure, `overflow-x: visible` is still there?

Comment: Just added the code to the post :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.scroll {
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
height:51.5em;
min-width:100%;
}
```

Turn `min-width` into `width`.

If you don't constrain the element's width, it will grow with its contents, thus never needing to scroll.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. The width of the container changes how it should, but scrollbar still unaccessable

Comment: @user I see a scroll bar in Chrome on OS X?

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you have the right stylesheet? Have you tried a refresh? This is what it looks like for me:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/LWbz1.jpg

Comment: hmm :/ tried safari and there is no scrollbar... could it be a problem with OSX Mavericks?

Comment: @user Are you sure there is no scroll bar when you hover over where it should be?

Comment: Ok it was Mavericks -.- In the general settings the scrollbars, where "automatic", which means no scrollbars :/

Comment: @user you should be seeing them when you hover over them with the mouse, though. Is that not the case? Because if it isn't, your site won't work for other Mavericks users.

Comment: The setting was one reason. The other reason is, I have a trackpad connected, while this is connected there aren't scrollbars. When I disconnect it, the scrollbars become visible...

Comment: Right. I remember this "feature", it's super annoying and it was the first thing I turned off after the update. And it's a problem for situations like these, although I guess a trackpad user will think to swipe and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4C3UQ/

Check this one. I have added some text in it so that you can see what happens. I used `overflow-x: auto;` so that the browser does it itself, when needed. If you put your images in here now, it should work.